# How to center a \chapter

Tags: chapters, alignment

I'm new in writing documents using `LaTeX`.

Can someone help me to center this chapter section? They are all right aligned. Here is a image of `.cls` which I believe is the command that creates the section header.

[image]

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I wonder if you are looking for the titlesec package.

Comment: Could you post a compilable code, not an image. Which document class do use anyway?

Comment: The template you are using does set the chapter headers right aligned for a reason. If you want it different, you might be lucky with a different template.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using one of the built-in document classes (book, report) then use the sectsty package which lets you change the style and font of headings, eg

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\centering}
```

If you are using a third-party (eg publisher's) document class (and it looks like you are), then you shouldn't be changing anything because it's set up the way they require you to use it (that is, it's *their* format. not yours).

I'm not clear what the image of an Abstract has to do with centering the chapter title. Or did you mean you want the Abstract title centered?

Comment: Yes,that's what I meant Peter. I want the abstract and other titles centered.

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\centering}  

Worked fine! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
```

Also works